# Get last several nodes in XSL, spanning parents

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have XML that looks like this:

```
<2011>
  <05>
    (item)
    (item)
  </05>
  <06>
    (item)
  </06>
</2011>
```

I'd like to get the last three items. However, I can't just get the last three items of the last item in the list, because sometimes that last item doesn't have three (in this example, it's if we're in a new month and there's only one item posted so far).

How do I go about getting the last three items without worrying about which parent they belong to?

Comment: Provided data isn't well-formed XML.

Comment: I was giving it as a broad example. I'm using a CMS which doesn't provide the raw XML.

Comment: What's `(item)` for you? a text or an element?

Comment: Supposed XML: `<root>
  <item>
    <element id="1"/>
  </item>
  <item>
    <element id="2"/>
  </item>
  <item>
    <element id="3"/>
  </item>
  <item>
    <element id="4"/>
    <element id="5"/>
  </item>
</root>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the XSLT I was speaking  about, assuming the @polishchuk input:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select="(/*/*/*)[position()>last()-3]"/>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: +1, and add my input to your answer, so I can delete my answer.